# How can I change the path of group_vars and host_vars?

Tags: ansible

we can change the path of roles by modifying `roles_path` in `ansible.cfg`.
But the document doesn't seems to mention anything about changing the path of `group_vars` and `host_vars`.

How can I change those paths?

I will integrate the files related to ansible with rails app repsitory.
I want to gather the roles and vars directory under single directory but leave hosts file and ansible.cfg at the top directory so that the top directory is easy to see and still I can run `ansible-playbook` at the top directory without moving to deep directory.

Thanks, in advance.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You cannot change the path for `host_vars` nor `group_vars`.

Those paths are always relative to your `hostfile`. You can set a standard hostfile in your ansible config:

```
hostfile = /path/to/hostfile/hostfile.ini
```

in this case your default `host_vars` are to be found at

```
/path/to/hostfile/host_vars/
```

You might as well use multiple hostfiles, assume you got:

```
/path/to/your/project/inventory/inventory.ini
```

with the `host_vars` at

```
/path/to/your/project/inventory/host_vars/
```

In this case you might call ansible from anywhere using:

```
ansible -i /path/to/your/project/inventory/inventory.ini my_playbook.yml
```

Just remember: the `host_vars` and `group_vars` are related to your `inventory (hostfile)` and therefore you can change your `inventory` location and put the according `host_vars` below it.

Comment: Thank you!@ProfHase85
I've decided to place hostfile together with group_vars in the directory one level deep And then execute `ansible-playbook` with `-i` from the top directory.

Comment: Another location (that has priority over host_vars/group_vars next to the inventory file) is in the same directory as the playbook itself. It's a shame that this location is not configurable either, because it effectively keeps you from having a proper directory tree structure for the playbook files.

Comment: Incongruence found: "The ansible-playbook command looks for these directories in the current working directory by default. Other Ansible commands (for example, ansible, ansible-console, and so on) will only look for group_vars/ and host_vars/ in the inventory directory." I think that makes this answer misleading when you write "paths are always relative to your hostfile." (or the official documentation is wrong) Source: https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/intro_inventory.html

Comment: @JonathanKomar The doc you cited continues by saying "If you want other commands to load group and host variables from a playbook directory, you must provide the --playbook-dir option on the command line" and it worked as advertised in my case using ansible (2.9 even) command where inventory and playbooks/group_vars are discrete directories under the working dir.

Comment: That was my point. I.e. Either this answer is misleading about paths being "always" relative to the host file, or the the docs are lying. It turns out, the docs are correct, which means, sometimes you must be explicit (so only sometimes are host_vars and group_vars relative to the hostfile). Or maybe I missed something.